# Flutter make GridView from json array

Tags: flutter

is any solution to make `GridView` with this structure? for example?

grid data are:

```
{
  'icon':Icons.home,
  'title':'dashboard'
},
```

i try to implementing this code

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    children: <Map<String,String>>[
      {
        'icon':Icons.home,
        'title':'dashboard'
      },
    ].map((Map<String,String> item) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(IconData(item['icon']))
            Text(item['title']),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList()),
```

Answer (score 0):

There need to give map type is `dynamic` like as  `<Map<String,dynamic>>`
instead of `<Map<String,String>>` `String` and `IconData` type, 
becuase of there are String and IconData type data into your map data, which String can't assigned to type of IconData and vice versa

```
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: <Map<String,dynamic>>[
          {
            'icon':Icons.home,
            'title':'dashboard'
          },
        ].map((Map<String,dynamic> item) {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(item['icon']),
                Text(item['title']),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList())
```

this help you